# WPF binding query - toggle button in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to create a column in a `DataGrid` containing a `ToggleButton`. The button's `IsChecked` property is bound to a property called `IsSelected` in my data item (implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

My first attempt failed to update `IsSelected` when the button is clicked, even though it correctly displayed the value when set elsewhere.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataItem}">
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Searching around stackexchange, I found a couple of solutions:

Setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataItem}">
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

or using relative binding

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataItem}">
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=DataContext.IsSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My question is, why does using direct binding require explicitly setting `UpdateSourceTrigger`, whereas the relative binding method does not?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `DataGrid` has an internal transaction behaviour, implemented by `BindingGroup`, and it generally won't update the source until the edit is committed. If your data object implements the `IEditableObject` interface, you will notice that its `BeginEdit()` and `EndEdit()` methods will be called when you edit a cell value.

Please refer to the following thread on the MSDN forums for more information about this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f7196b8-b9dc-487d-93cd-e77f5b3d9906/confused-about-transactional-editing-edititemcanceledit?forum=wpf

Comment: I understand totally why the direct binding case requires UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to work correctly. However, your answer doesn't address the key point of my question - why the binding using RelativeSource does not require the same binding parameters to be specified.

Comment: In the second example you are binding to a property of a DataGridCell and not directly to a property of the underlying data object.